# Wir brauchen eine Liste von Referenzen!

Tags: discussion, reference

Ich frage mich gerade, wie ein Suchender Fragen stellt. Wir schließen Fragen oft, weil diese mehr oder weniger einfach durch Recherche selbst beantwortet werden kann. Wie und wo man nachschauen soll steht aber nirgends. Für uns ist das vielleicht klar, aber für jemanden, der die Sprache lernt?

Ich denke mal es gibt keine solche Liste, da es keine "offiziellen" Seite/Nachschlagewerk gibt. Ich hatte sowas ja schon mal [angefragt](https://german.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1281/verlinkung-zu-standardverzeichnissen-und-referenzen-gibt-es-diese-%C3%BCberhaupt). Allerdings empfinde ich den Nachteil keine Nachschlagewerke aus Neutralitätsgründen offiziell zu nennen größer, als der Nachteil nicht darauf offiziell verweisen zu können. Ich stelle mir eine Seite vor, die Fragen versucht zu kategorisieren und dann ggf. mehrere Quellen nennt.

Beispiele:

- Ich suche den richtigen Fall für ein Wort
- Ich suche eine gute Übersetzung
- Ich suche Regeln der Deutschen Sprache

Das ließe sich natürlich nach Belieben fein aufgliedern, aber ich denke es könnte helfen, die Qualität der Fragen zu erhöhen. Die verlinkten Werke und Seiten könnten durch Abstimmung aufgenommen oder verworfen werden.

Wer für eine solche Liste ist und dies für praktikabel hält, sollte meine Frage upvoten, wenn dagegen gerne downvoten.

Comment: Nur zur Rekapitulation und weil es da immer wieder Irritationen gibt: ein Downvote auf Meta heißt nicht, dass die Frage schlecht ist sondern nur, dass man mit der Idee nicht einverstanden ist. Hier also, dass wir keine solche Liste brauchen.

Comment: Beachte, dass die meisten Fragen, die wir mit Verweis auf *general reference* schließen, hierdurch keinen Deut besser würden. Wir bombardieren Fragesteller bereits mit Hinweisen, so gut es das Stack-Exchange-System erlaubt ([1](https://german.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1231/2594), [2](https://german.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1105/2594)). Das Problem ist, dass diese Hinweise missachtet werden.

Comment: @Wrzlprmft Ich sehe das anders, unsere Hinweise sind zu allgemein, um wirklich eine Hilfe zu sein, nur konkrete Angaben mit eindeutigen Verweisen würden das verbessern. Unsere Hinweise folgen immer im Nachhinein. Klar, das Abschaffen von einfachen Fragen ist zu utopisch, aber ich bin von dem Nutzen einer Hilfeseite dieser Art überzeugt.

Comment: @Thomas: dass unsere Hinweise in **Nachhinein** kommen ist ein Jammer, wirklich. Man könnte sich auch von einer ganz arg freundlichen Seite zeigen und anstatt solche Fragen kommentarlos (!) mit einem Standardtext zu schließen etwas in der Art schreiben: *Have a look in `[this](link)` great dictionary. You should find your answer there. If not, don't hesitate to tell us where your issues are.* - Wenn darauf nach angemessener Zeit (Tage eher denn Minuten) keine Antwort kommt, können man *on hold* als *unclear* setzen . Solange die Frage nicht beantwortet wird, verschwindet sie sowieso.

Comment: @Takkat Du sprichst tatsächlich eine Möglichkeit an, die ich auch als Kompromiss noch vorschlagen wollte: Differenzierterte Ablehnungsantworten mit konkreten Hinweisen auf mögliche Hilfen. Ich stelle mir einen Katalog vor, der bestimmte Standardfragen versucht abzudecken. Diese Antworten könnten dann per Copy und Paste aus einem langen FAQ in Meta gepostet werden. Dennoch kommen wir auch dort um den einen Punkt nicht herum, wir müssen Referenzen nennen.

Comment: @Thomas: bei so wenigen Fragen können wir uns doch auch die Zeit nehmen, jede Frage **individuell** zu kommentieren. Schließlich haben sich die meisten Leute Mühe gegeben, ihre Frage zu formulieren. Bei Usern, deren Status noch `[unregistered]` ist, differenziere ich, ob ich sie gerne als `ŗegistered` gewinnen möchte (das wäre der Weg, den wir alle gehen sollten!) oder ob ich meine, sie können wegbleiben (finde ich nur selten).  Nur im letzteren Fall gibt es dann die vorgefertigte kommentarlose Abfuhr, die dann ein neuer Benutzer leider als  "Bleib weg mit Deinen Schrottfragen" auffassen wird.

Comment: @Takkat Sicher, es sind nicht viele Fragen, allerdings versuche ich GL methodisch zu verbessern, mir ist das "simple" Frage/Antwort-Spiel zu wenig. Verstehe mich nicht falsch, das Prinzip ist Klasse bis zu einem bestimmten Punkt, aber dann wird daraus nix weiter gemacht. Das stört mich. Vielleicht will ich zu viel und es scheint ja nicht viele Leute zu geben, die sich darum scheren. Wenn das so gewollt ist, verstumme ich lieber.

Comment: @Thomas: nein, mach weiter! Wir sind eine Community-Seite. Jeder Beitrag ist total wichtig, aber man muss halt für alles die Zustimmung der Mitglieder einholen. Bei eine unteridischen Metabeteiligung (hier 50 views, 5 Votes, nur eine Antwort)  ist das mitunter sehr beschwerlich, aber dennoch es sind Benutzer wie Du, die das Aussehen der Seite beeinflussen - da wird nur der grobe Rahmen von SE vorgegeben (der muss aber eingehalten werden).

Answer (score 2):

Solange es nicht eindeutig geklärt ist, dass unsere Benutzer nicht in **allen** diesen Referenzwerken nachschlagen müssen, um nicht zu riskieren, dass ihre Frage hier *off topic* wird, bin ich gegen eine solche "verbindliche" Liste.

[Eine unverbindliche Liste gibt es schon](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/9526/resources-for-learning-german).

Welches Nachlagewerk nun gut ist, ist höchst subjektiv, denn jeder mag ein anderes Werk lieber, wir werden uns da nicht einig. Anfänger können mit dem umfassenden Werk wenig anfangen, das Fortgeschrittene toll finden.

Wir möchten aber für alle da sein.

Viel entscheidender ist meiner Meinung nach, dass die Fragenden uns sagen, was sie in **ihrem** Wörterbuch gefunden haben und was ihnen danach nicht klar war. Dann sollte man meinen, dass jedes Wörterbuch (nicht Übersetzungsroboter!) ausreichend sein sollte, uns zu zeigen, dass man sich bemüht hat (und nur darum geht es hoffentlich, denn eine einfach zu beantwortende Frage alleine ist kein Off-Topic-Grund).

Comment: Keiner findet diese unverbindliche Liste.

Comment: Dieses Problem hätte eine verbindliche Liste wahrscheinlich auch ;)

Comment: @Thomas Man könnte in Meta eine Art "FAQ-Frage" posten und als "featured question" sichtbar machen. Jede "Antwort" auf diese Frage wäre eigentlich eine wichtige Frage. Siehe z.B. [Let's compile a list of canonical Q&As](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2708/158988).

Comment: @ChristopheStrobbe Meta Fragen sind nur vorübergehend  "Featured" - nach einer Weile verblasst der Status und müßte neu angeschubts werden. Aber eine Liste von "canonical questions" ist schon ganz hilfreich: https://german.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/987/for-which-recurring-topics-do-we-want-to-create-canonical-answers-if-any

Comment: @thomas Mein Google findet unter "Deutsches Wörterbuch" und "German dictionary" wesentlich mehr als die in der Liste aufgeführten. German Stack Exchange findet es nicht ;) (Soll heissen, wer GSE finden kann, ist auch in der Lage, ein Wörterbuch zu finden)

Comment: @tofro Es geht mir hier nicht um eine simple Suche in einer (evil) Suchmaschine deiner Wahl, es geht mir um eine strukturierte Anleitung, Verstehen und Lernen der Deutschen Sprache. Dazu gehören simple Wörterbücher, Rechtschreibregeln, Wortlisten, Sprichwörter, aber auch Perlen wie Atlas der deutschen Sprache, Ngram-Viewer usw. und so fort, selbst für mich als Deutscher ist es nicht einfach mal eben so etwas aufzuspüren und ich bin immer wieder erstaunt, was hier so auftaucht. Ich möchte dieses Wissen in eine strukturierte Form bringen.

Comment: @Thomas Das ist löblich. Das Problem ist nur: Wenn du das alles aufgelistet hast, wo tust du es hin?  Grade "Anfänger" auf der Site sind es nicht gewohnt in alten Antworten zu stöbern, um deine Perlen zu finden, sie stellen lieber eine neue Frage, weil so anscheinend GSE funktioniert. Der Versuch, im "Ur-SE" eine Dokumentationsabteilung einzurichten, in der man solche information hätte unterbringen können. ist auch kläglich gescheitert. GSE ist halt kein Wiki.

Comment: @tofro Ja, da war was, hast du mehr Informationen zum grandiosen Scheitern der Doku (Hintergünde)?

Comment: Habe es gefunden: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/354217/sunsetting-documentation